# Symfony Twig parse Json

Tags: symfony, twig

I have route that is using cUrl.
The cUrl returns Json data.
So, I did `$data = json_decode($results);`

It returns:

```
(
    .....
    [dovecot] => stdClass Object
        (
            [info_str] => Running
            [name] => Dovecot
            [version] => 2.3.4
        )

    [exim] => stdClass Object
        (
            [info_str] => Running
            [name] => Exim
            [version] => 4.91
        )
    .......
}
```

So when I do `return $data;` on my route to twig and do:

```
{% for info in data %}
    {{ info }}
{% endfor %}
```

It doesn't show anything.

My point point is to print only the `[name]`, so I also tried:

```
{% for info in data %}
    {{ info.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

And it's not working.

Comment: $data = json_decode($results,true); to make associative array

Comment: try in twig {{dump(data)}} and comment that it returns